# C# Creating SQLite database in ASP.NET in Release results in empty database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

I'm having a strange issue where after I create and populate a SQLite database on the webserver, it is completely empty after I download it.
Here's snippets of what I'm doing.

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sqlitePath))
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(sqlitePath);
else
{
    File.Delete(sqlitePath);
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(sqlitePath);
}
```

This is the SQL statement loaded from a text file:

```
CREATE TABLE "tblDriver" (
    `Driver_KeyID`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `FirstName` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `LastName`  TEXT NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(`Driver_KeyID`)
)
```

And executed via this method

```
public void ExecuteSQLiteCommand(List<string> queries, string sqlitePath)
{
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format(@"Data Source={0};Version=3;", sqlitePath)))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SQLiteTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                foreach (var qry in queries)
                {
                    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, conn);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I then populate the database with

```
string driverInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO `tblDriver` (`Driver_KeyID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`) VALUES ";

var drivervalues = (from d in drivers.AsEnumerable()
                    select string.Format("({0}, '{1}', '{2}')",
                        int.Parse(d["KeyID"].ToString()),
                        d["FirstName"].ToString(),
                        d["LastName"].ToString()
                    )
                );

foreach (var item in drivervalues)
{
    driverList.Add(string.Format("{0}{1}", driverInsertSQL, item));
}

ExecuteSQLiteCommand(driverList, sqlitePath);
```

I then download the file.  When I'm in DEBUG, the database is populated with all my data, but when I'm in RELEASE, there are not even tables.
In a console app with this exact same code, it populates the database in either DEBUG or RELEASE.

It appears as if it isn't committing the data in RELEASE--even after I added the `SQLiteTransaction` piece.

Any ideas?

Comment: does `sqlitePath` contain the full directory name? i'm suspecting you're not finding the correct file...

Comment: Yes, it does. And I'm only using one file name so there's no chance of it grabbing any other file.  Same filename each time.  So if it exists, it deletes it and recreates it.

Comment: You said you're using “one file name” but Lei asked about your “directory name”. Those are different things. What's the value of `sqlitePath`?

Comment: I realize this and I mentioned "file name" for a reason.  The full directory path includes the filename in order to populate the connection string.  I'll post the value of `sqlitePath` in a moment.

Comment: `C:\TestWebApp\root\generated-multiload\MULTILOAD.B`

Comment: you say that you need 'download' the file, it means you're debugging a big web project. so there should possibly be impacts of code elsewhere. if you can provide a  minimal console app to reproduce that will be great.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MNuEaM  I put this together real quick.  Should be able to pull this out into a console app fairly quickly.  Obviously, the `dotnetfiddle` emulator is giving a security exception because it's trying to write to the environment path.

Comment: Also, I am downloading the file just fine.  The problem is that the database is completely empty when I am running the site in RELEASE.  No errors are thrown during the creation/save process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
`SQLite.Interop.dll` wasn't being updated in the /bin/ directory.  I still had an older version even after I updated via nuget.

Comment: so when you say 'no exception', it may be your exception settings issue.

Comment: so when you say 'no exception', it may be your exception settings issue.

Comment: Perhaps, I get other errors just fine.  Very strange.

Comment: 1. go to project settings and debug tab, enable native debugging 2. set a break point and debug, there's a window of exception type selection.

Comment: Thank you, @LeiYang , I'm debugging just fine, though.  An error was just never thrown.